# OSR Python testSR.ImportFromEPSG(4326) returns empty spatial reference

Tags: python, ogr

This is empty using Python .ImportFromEPSG(4326):

```
from osgeo import osr
#this fails:
testSR = osr.SpatialReference()
testSR.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
print testSR.ExportToPrettyWkt()

#why did the import from EPSG fail above?
testSR.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84")
print testSR.ExportToPrettyWkt()
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
DATUM["WGS_1984", and so on...
```

Comment: Do you need to get the list using Python? Or would just getting the list work?

Comment: What version of ogr are you using?

Comment: help(osr)
Help on module osr:

NAME
    osr - # import osgeo.osr as a convenience

FILE
    c:\python27\arcgis10.1\lib\site-packages\osr.py

Comment: `testSR.ImportFromEPSG('4326')`?  Do you need to pass a `str` instead of an `int`? - Also, make sure to go back and accept some answers to your other questions.

Comment: Make sure GDAL_DATA is set to the proper location.  It may be that the EPSG import is failing because it can't find the files.

Comment: @user10353, what is the proper location of GDAL_DATA? I can't find it in /usr/share/gdal/2.2/

Answer (score 9):

First, the real error was skipped, since `ImportFromEPSG` returned a non-zero error code:

```
from osgeo import osr
testSR = osr.SpatialReference()
res = testSR.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
if res != 0:
    raise RuntimeError(repr(res) + ': could not import from EPSG')
print testSR.ExportToPrettyWkt()
```

Now the cause. GDAL needs an environment variable `GDAL_DATA` to find and use projection info. If it is not available, then some things stop working. The SRID look-up codes are in `GDAL_DATA`, for instance. Check if you have it:

```
import os
'GDAL_DATA' in os.environ
```

if `False`, it should be added to either your system's environment variables, or you can add it in run-time:

```
if 'GDAL_DATA' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = r'/path/to/gdal_data'
```

Comment: If you set `GDAL_DATA` at run-time, you need to do that before you import `osr` and `gdal`

Comment: also, what is the difference between GDAL_PATH and GDAL_DATA

Comment: Very helpful, my path on Ubuntu is  /usr/share/gdal/2.1

Comment: @RutgerH you've found a typo (there is no such thing as "GDAL_PATH"), all fixed, thanks!

Comment: Anyway I had RuntimeError: 7: could not import from EPSG... and False when checking if 'GDAL_DATA' in os.environ. Although I specified os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = r'/usr/share/gdal/2.2/'   What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to define test1 first

```
from osgeo import osr
test1 = osr.SpatialReference() #define test1
test1.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
print test1.ExportToPrettyWkt()
```

Only then can you call the ExportToPrettyWkt() function. Which should result in the following output:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

Comment: This returns an empty spatial reference:    import osr
    testSR = osr.SpatialReference()
    testSR.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    print testSR.ExportToPrettyWkt()

Comment: You mean the print statement does not print anything for you?

Comment: Correct.  testSR.ImportFromEPSG(4326);    txtTest =  testSR.ExportToPrettyWkt();    len(txtTest) is zero  while   testSR.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");    txtTest =  testSR.ExportToPrettyWkt() returns a string of 357 chars

Comment: What is your question btw? Now I'm confused. Is it to fix the error or to get the list of ESPG values? `Where can I get a list of EPSG values for common spatial references?`
Also, how did you install your osr and what version are you using?

Comment: testSR.ImportFromEPSG(4326) returns an empty spatial reference osr is from:  c:\python27\arcgis10.1\lib\site-packages\osr.py

Comment: Can you check if gcs.csv exists? It's where the list of EPSG codes are stored.

Comment: what is the typical path to gcs.csv?  If it does not exist, where can I download it from and what path should I move it to?