# Create a georeferenced raster from a matrix

Tags: gdal, python-2.7

I am trying to create a WGS84 raster from a matrix like so:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

test = np.random.random((64, 128))
nx = test.shape[0]
ny = test.shape[1]

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = [-180, -90, 180, 90]

xres = (xmax - xmin) / float(nx)
yres = (ymax - ymin) / float(ny)
geotransform = (xmin, xres, 0, ymax, 0, -yres)


dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('Z:/spotter/output.tif', ny, nx, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)


dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)    
srs = osr.SpatialReference()            
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)                # WGS84 lat/long
```

but `srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)` returns `6` and isn't being set properly.

```
g = gdal.Open('Z:/spotter/output.tif')
g.GetProjection()
```

returns empty brackets, `''`

Comment: Does gdalinfo recognize it?

Comment: opening the out put up as `g = gdal.Open('Z:/spotter/output.tif')` and `g.GetProjection()` returns empty brackets

Comment: You might check the SetProjection call by immediately calling GetProjection on it to see if it worked properly.

Comment: it appears `srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)` returns `6`, and no it is net being set properly in the first place

Comment: I guess you need also `from osgeo import osr`

Comment: Yea I did actually, just forgot to show that here, I just imported a WGS84 raster and pull the projection info from that and it works.  Not sure why the EPSG doesn't work though

Comment: Perhaps problem with GDAL_DATA https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/osr-python-testsr-importfromepsg4326-returns-empty-spatial-reference.